# How to extract integer from C style const char* array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to extract an integer from a C style const char* array.

So far I have this:

```
int Suite::extractParameter(const char* data)
{
    //Example data "s_reg2=96"

    const char *ptr = strchr(data, '=');
    if(ptr)
    {
        int index = ptr - data;

        //Get substring ie. "96"

        //Convert substring to int and return
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to extract the sub string and then convert it to an integer.

The integer to be extracted is between 0 and 9999.

Comment: `long number = strtol(&ptr[1], NULL, 0);`?

Comment: `int index = atoi(ptr+1)`; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string always comes at the end, right after the `'='` character, you could use [`std::atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi):

```
const char *ptr = strchr(data, '=');
if(ptr && *(ptr+1)) { // it's not NULL and not the last character
    int val = std::atoi(ptr+1);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/P3ZItj)

Comment: Looks perfect, thanks. Does std::atoi read from the pointer location until it sees a terminating char '\0'?

Comment: @JosephRoberts: `std::atoi` reads until it sees a non-integer character. E.g., `std::atoi("23adfa2")` should return `23`.